# How can I convert this array to c#?

Tags: c#, php, arrays

I have the following array made in PHP and I need to convert it to c#

```
public $Cards = array("Player" => array(), "Bank" => array());
```

I tried doing the following

```
    object[] cards = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Player", string},
        {"Dealer", string}
    };
```

But it seems to be failing, what is the optimum way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>cards = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
    {
        {"Player", new List<string>()},
        {"Dealer", new List<string>()}
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can work with `Dictionaries` (which are not *arrays*):

```
  // First (as you've mentioned in the comment) you need a Card class
  public class Card {
    public String Suit { get; private set; }
    public String Value { get; private set; }
    public String Face { get; private set; }
    ...   
  }

  // An so you have a dictionary solution
  Dictionary<string, List<Card>> cards = new Dictionary<string, List<Card>>() {
    {"Player", new List<Card>()}, 
    {"Dealer", new List<Card>()}
  };
```

Or if you want *arrays* you should put it differently (but it's a *combersome* design):

```
  // ... or array solution  
  Tuple<String, List<Card>>[] cards = new Tuple<String, List<Card>>[] {
    new Tuple<String, List<Card>>("Player", new List<Card>()), 
    new Tuple<String, List<Card>>("Dealer", new List<Card>())
  };
```

Comment: It won't hold the cards as a string but inside "Player" there will be different arrays, each array containing a face key, value key and suit key